No pg_hba.conf entry for host 179.91.20.14 while connecting RDS from Lambda
Getting the below given error even after setting all inbound and outbound rules, IAM role for Lambda, making RDS and Lambda both under the same VPC, allowed traffic on port 5432 from the security group associated with your Lambda function and from lambda allowed traffic to the RDS instance on port 5432. I know that entry on pg_hba.conf is missing, not sure how that could be added on aws RDS, So have no idea why does it give the following error

which version of postgresql are you using?

See linked answer. You need to use SSL in the connection.
